1980's Sci Fi: Earth protects by sending animals & children from current world to a parallel earth that had a small nuclear event in the cold war
I remember this wonderful book following a cast of characters in a New England town:  in one Earth, the cold war had led to a nuclear in the US and only small pockets of civilization survived.  In the other Earth, life continued but about to go up in a more devastating, world-ending nuclear event in the 1980's or 90's.  Both characters and their different lives were followed:  in the first world (ours), an alcoholic homeless man -- in the second, "earlier nuke" world, a respected member of the community who runs a still.  In the first:  a music producer visits his favorite star; in the second, a busker travels from town to town.  Children who died in one world cross over into the other.  Animals cross over into the other world. The Earth is seen as protecting its life.
